# Laravel 4.2 Application redirecting to untrusted site after login

Tags: php, security, laravel-4

A few days back my application, developed in laravel 4.2, is redirected to a suspicious screen after login. This happened for the first time in that browser. From next time it is working fine. I checked the code and did not find anything suspicious.

After searching, I found that it is called an open redirection vulnerability, but couldn't find any solution.

Can you help me to fix this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoKUs.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this link maybe it will help you https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-internet-security-alert-code-055bccac9fec/

Comment: Thank you Parthi. Can this malware be through the application? Or it can be only through system or browser?

Comment: Post the login code

Comment: thegreatcontini, I have checked the code completely.  What are the places where anyone can redirect the application from the server. Like vhost,  etc. Can anyone help me to find out those places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been resolved.

Previously we had Drupal website on the same server. Through website hackers got access to the server and they placed some base64 encoded script.

This script is placed in database.php file and many other places. So whenever application is connecting to db i.e soon after login, redirection is happening. This is happening only for first time as they are setting cookies.

I have searched with @eval and @eval( base64_decode throughout the system to find out the files.

Hope this will help someone.